# How to parse such JSON with Gson?

Tags: android, json, parsing, gson, retrofit

I've got a JSON with this structure:

```
{
"response": {
    "2018-11-19": [
        {
            "date_end": {
                "year": "2018",
                "day_verbose": "Sun",
                "month": "11",
                "month_verbose": "Nov",
                "time": "10:30",
                "iso": "2018-11-19T10:30:00",
                "day": "19"
            },
            "date_start": {
                "year": "2018",
                "day_verbose": "Sun",
                "month": "11",
                "month_verbose": "Nov",
                "time": "08:00",
                "iso": "2018-11-19T08:00:00",
                "day": "19"
            },
            "id": "20181119080000001018"
        },
        {
            "date_end": {
                "year": "2018",
                "day_verbose": "Sun",
                "month": "11",
                "month_verbose": "Nov",
                "time": "10:30",
                "iso": "2018-11-19T10:30:00",
                "day": "19"
            },
            "date_start": {
                "year": "2018",
                "day_verbose": "Sun",
                "month": "11",
                "month_verbose": "Nov",
                "time": "09:30",
                "iso": "2018-11-19T09:30:00",
                "day": "19"
            },
            "id": "20181119093000001018"
        },
        {
            "date_end": {
                "year": "2018",
                "day_verbose": "Sun",
                "month": "11",
                "month_verbose": "Nov",
                "time": "10:30",
                "iso": "2018-11-19T10:30:00",
                "day": "19"
            },
            "date_start": {
                "year": "2018",
                "day_verbose": "Sun",
                "month": "11",
                "month_verbose": "Nov",
                "time": "10:00",
                "iso": "2018-11-19T10:00:00",
                "day": "19"
            },
            "id": "20181119100000001018"
        },
        {
            "date_end": {
                "year": "2018",
                "day_verbose": "Sun",
                "month": "11",
                "month_verbose": "Nov",
                "time": "10:30",
                "iso": "2018-11-19T10:30:00",
                "day": "19"
            },
            "date_start": {
                "year": "2018",
                "day_verbose": "Sun",
                "month": "11",
                "month_verbose": "Nov",
                "time": "10:30",
                "iso": "2018-11-19T10:30:00",
                "day": "19"
            },
            "id": "20181119103000001018"
        }
    ],
    "2018-11-16": [
        {
            "date_end": {
                "year": "2018",
                "day_verbose": "Sun",
                "month": "11",
                "month_verbose": "Nov",
                "time": "11:15",
                "iso": "2018-11-16T11:15:00",
                "day": "16"
            },
            "date_start": {
                "year": "2018",
                "day_verbose": "Sun",
                "month": "11",
                "month_verbose": "Nov",
                "time": "10:00",
                "iso": "2018-11-16T10:00:00",
                "day": "16"
            },
            "id": "20181116100000001018"
        },
        {
            "date_end": {
                "year": "2018",
                "day_verbose": "Sun",
                "month": "11",
                "month_verbose": "Nov",
                "time": "11:15",
                "iso": "2018-11-16T11:15:00",
                "day": "16"
            },
            "date_start": {
                "year": "2018",
                "day_verbose": "Sun",
                "month": "11",
                "month_verbose": "Nov",
                "time": "11:15",
                "iso": "2018-11-16T11:15:00",
                "day": "16"
            },
            "id": "20181116111500001018"
        }
    ]
},
"success": true,
"error": {}
}
```

The main difficulty that there can be many objects like "2018-11-19". And their names are unknown beforehand.
I can parse "success" field and "Error" object but I've got troubles with the "Response" object. I receive "OK" HTTP code with null Response object. I think that there's something wrong with mapping.
Here are my classes for mapping:

```
public class AppointmentListApiResponse extends ApiResponse {

@SerializedName("response")
@Expose
private Response response;
@SerializedName("success")
@Expose
private Boolean success;
@SerializedName("error")
@Expose
private Error error;

// getters and setters

public class Response {

    // I've tried these versions

    //private Map<String, AppointmentInfo> appoints;
    //private Map<String, List<AppointmentInfo>> appoints;
    //private List<List<AppointmentInfo>> appoints;

    // but they don't work for me

    // getters and setters
}
```

And this is AppointmentInfo class:

```
public class AppointmentInfo {
@SerializedName("date_start")
@Expose
private Date dateStart;

@SerializedName("date_end")
@Expose
private Date dateEnd;

@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
private String id;

// getters and setters


public class Date {
    @SerializedName("day")
    @Expose
    private String day;

    @SerializedName("day_verbose")
    @Expose
    private String dayVerbose;

    @SerializedName("iso")
    @Expose
    private String dateTime;

    @SerializedName("month")
    @Expose
    private String month;

    @SerializedName("month_verbose")
    @Expose
    private String monthVerbose;

    @SerializedName("time")
    @Expose
    private String time;

    @SerializedName("year")
    @Expose
    private String year;

    // getters and setters
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally found the solution. The class should be like this:

```
public class AppointmentListApiResponse extends ApiResponse {

     @SerializedName("response")
     private Map<String, List<AppointmentInfo>> response;
     @SerializedName("success")
     private Boolean success;
     @SerializedName("error")
     private Error error;
}
```

And it doesn't need Response class inside. Hope this will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

model of that response of json string and use APIResponse class to parse the json string using gson library

```
public class APIResponse{

@SerializedName("response")
@Expose
public Response response;
@SerializedName("success")
@Expose
public Boolean success;
@SerializedName("error")
@Expose
public Error error;

}

public class Response {

@SerializedName("2018-11-19")
@Expose
public List<com.example._20181119> _20181119 = null;
@SerializedName("2018-11-16")
@Expose
public List<com.example._20181116> _20181116 = null;

}

public class DateEnd {

@SerializedName("year")
@Expose
public String year;
@SerializedName("day_verbose")
@Expose
public String dayVerbose;
@SerializedName("month")
@Expose
public String month;
@SerializedName("month_verbose")
@Expose
public String monthVerbose;
@SerializedName("time")
@Expose
public String time;
@SerializedName("iso")
@Expose
public String iso;
@SerializedName("day")
@Expose
public String day;

}

public class DateEnd_ {

@SerializedName("year")
@Expose
public String year;
@SerializedName("day_verbose")
@Expose
public String dayVerbose;
@SerializedName("month")
@Expose
public String month;
@SerializedName("month_verbose")
@Expose
public String monthVerbose;
@SerializedName("time")
@Expose
public String time;
@SerializedName("iso")
@Expose
public String iso;
@SerializedName("day")
@Expose
public String day;

}

public class DateStart {

@SerializedName("year")
@Expose
public String year;
@SerializedName("day_verbose")
@Expose
public String dayVerbose;
@SerializedName("month")
@Expose
public String month;
@SerializedName("month_verbose")
@Expose
public String monthVerbose;
@SerializedName("time")
@Expose
public String time;
@SerializedName("iso")
@Expose
public String iso;
@SerializedName("day")
@Expose
public String day;

}

public class DateStart_ {

@SerializedName("year")
@Expose
public String year;
@SerializedName("day_verbose")
@Expose
public String dayVerbose;
@SerializedName("month")
@Expose
public String month;
@SerializedName("month_verbose")
@Expose
public String monthVerbose;
@SerializedName("time")
@Expose
public String time;
@SerializedName("iso")
@Expose
public String iso;
@SerializedName("day")
@Expose
public String day;

}

public class Error {


}



public class _20181116 {

@SerializedName("date_end")
@Expose
public DateEnd_ dateEnd;
@SerializedName("date_start")
@Expose
public DateStart_ dateStart;
@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
public String id;

}

public class _20181119 {

@SerializedName("date_end")
@Expose
public DateEnd dateEnd;
@SerializedName("date_start")
@Expose
public DateStart dateStart;
@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
public String id;

}
```

Comment: It's a little bit strange solution, isn't it? I always get different objects ("2018-11-19", "2018-11-16"). Their names depend on current date and other different things. That's why I can't map these objects by their names

Answer (score 0):

For your fixed/static keys models, create POJOs for instance -

`"date_end": {
                "year": "2018",
                "day_verbose": "Sun",
                "month": "11",
                "month_verbose": "Nov",
                "time": "10:30",
                "iso": "2018-11-19T10:30:00",
                "day": "19"
            }`

This can be mapped by

```
public class Date_End {
@SerializedName("year")
public String year;
@SerializedName("day_verbose")
public String dayVerbose;
@SerializedName("month")
public String month;
@SerializedName("monthVerbose")
public String monthVerbose;
@SerializedName("time")
public String time;
// and similarly other fields
}
```

Create a wrapper POJO for Date_END and Date_Start

```
public class DateStartEndWrapper {
@SerializedName("date_end")
public Date_End dateEnd;
@SerializedName("date_start")
public Date_Start dateStart;
}
```

For your outer dynamic keys such as "2018-11-19" consider the response as a Map and parse it using -

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Type mapType = new TypeToken<Map<String,DateStartEndWrapper>() {}.getType();
gson.fromJson() // pass the value of response key in here.
```